# Selecting Bold Text

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, richtext

I need to select only the bold text in a RichTextBox in a winform application and then enclose it within brackets :
For example: `The Rollup Action element describes the desired action that should be applied to the cluster activity that defines the Rollup Rule`.
 The bold text would become:
`[Rollup Action]  [Rollup Rule]`. Thanks.

Comment: winforms, Sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: In the result text you need only the bold text with brackets or all the text and just add brackets to the bold one?

Comment: I need all the text with brackets added to the bold segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use Regex to find the bold text and replace it with the same thing but with brackets added:

```
  richTextBox.Rtf = Regex.Replace(richTextBox.Rtf, @"\\b ((\w| )*)", RegExSample.AddBrackets);
```

And the MatchEvaluator:

```
public class RegExSample
{
      public static string AddBrackets(Match match)
      {
           return String.Format("[{0}]", match.Value);
      }
}
```

The output for your sample would be:

> The **[Rollup Action]** element describes
>   the desired action that should be
>   applied to the cluster activity that
>   defines the **[Rollup Rule]**

You can also update the regex to be sure it works ok in all cases.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, it works. However, when bold is combined with another format (italic for example), it continues to the next match. Is there an expression that includes all formatting possibilities?